# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas DBs in rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, mongodb-atlas

I'm a n00b to [rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/) and I'm trying to connect to a database on a MongoDB Atlas MongoDB version 4.0 cluster using [the mongodb rust crate v0.4.0](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.4.0/mongodb/index.html) with no luck.

In Atlas I've given firewall access and can connect from my home IP so it's def not a permission/access issue. I searched for the error but didn't find much help out there on this topic. Looks like the mongodb rust driver is still young and not fully baked.

The err I get is:

`thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: OperationError("No servers available for the provided ReadPreference.")'`

Backtrace details below:

```sh
Running `target/debug/gigs-core`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: OperationError("No servers available for the provided ReadPreference.")', src/libcore/result.rs:1165:5
stack backtrace:
   0: backtrace::backtrace::libunwind::trace
             at /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.40/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:88
   1: backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
             at /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.40/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:77
   3: <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:61
   4: core::fmt::write
             at src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:1028
   5: std::io::Write::write_fmt
             at src/libstd/io/mod.rs:1412
   6: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:65
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:50
   8: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:188
   9: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:205
  10: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:464
  11: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:373
  12: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:302
  13: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:139
  14: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at src/libcore/result.rs:1165
  15: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/91fd6283e658e2c7aab2d3f5206fc1891f486af2/src/libcore/result.rs:933
  16: gigs_core::main
             at src/main.rs:12
  17: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/91fd6283e658e2c7aab2d3f5206fc1891f486af2/src/libstd/rt.rs:61
  18: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/rt.rs:48
  19: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:287
  20: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:83
  21: std::panicking::try
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:265
  22: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at src/libstd/panic.rs:396
  23: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at src/libstd/rt.rs:47
  24: std::rt::lang_start
             at /rustc/91fd6283e658e2c7aab2d3f5206fc1891f486af2/src/libstd/rt.rs:61
  25: gigs_core::main
```

Here is the code I'm running with the cred obviously extracted:

```rust
use mongodb::{Bson, bson, doc};
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

fn main() {
    let mongodb_uri = String::from("mongodb://cluster0-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:2017, \
        cluster0-shard-00-00-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:27017, \
        cluster0-shard-00-00-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:27017/"
    );
    let client = Client::with_uri(&mongodb_uri)    
        .expect("Failed to initialize client.");
    client.db("admin").auth("username","password").unwrap();
    let coll = client.db("gigs_core").collection("events");
    let cursor = coll.find(None, None).unwrap();
    for result in cursor{
        if let Ok(item) = result {
            if let Some(&Bson::String(ref name)) = item.get("name"){
                println!("name : {}",name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone out there have any advise on connecting to a MongoDB Atlas DB using rust?

Comment: Copy exact Mongodb Atlas connection string from Atlas connect with... And replace user name and password with. And white list all IP address in Atlas security tab too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue before and fixed it by using the `with_unauthenticated_ssl` option.
(It seems like MongoDB Atlas requires an SSL connection.)

First, edit `Cargo.toml` to enable `"ssl"` feature of `mongodb`

```
mongodb = { version = "0.4.0", features = ["ssl"] }
```

and then use the `with_unauthenticated_ssl` option to create a client.

```rust
use mongodb::{Bson, bson, doc};
use mongodb::{Client, ClientOptions, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

fn main() {
    let mongodb_uri = String::from("mongodb://cluster0-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:2017, \
        cluster0-shard-00-00-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:27017, \
        cluster0-shard-00-00-kbbbhky.mongodb.net:27017/"
    );
    // Define options
    let opts = ClientOptions::with_unauthenticated_ssl(None, false);
    // Initialize with options
    let client = Client::with_uri_and_options(&mongodb_uri, opts)    
        .expect("Failed to initialize client.");
    client.db("admin").auth("username","password").unwrap();
    let coll = client.db("gigs_core").collection("events");
    let cursor = coll.find(None, None).unwrap();
    for result in cursor{
        if let Ok(item) = result {
            if let Some(&Bson::String(ref name)) = item.get("name"){
                println!("name : {}",name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your `mongodb_uri` doesn't look right. You should check that too.

Reference: https://medium.com/@shnarazk/connecting-mongodb-atlas-from-rust-programs-65e4cbcbd964

(The reference says you need to enable `"ssh"` feature, but it's a typo. `mongodb` crate doesn't have such a feature.)